# Kusto query for generating Azure function success and failure count line graph

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I need to create a time series chart showing the total successes and failures for an Azure function app. I couldn't find any in-built metric for function app that shows success and failures for a trigger function so I've written a Kusto query that gives me this information in a tabular manner. Here is the query-

```
requests
| project
    timestamp,
    operation_Name,
    success,
    resultCode,
    duration,
    operation_Id,
    cloud_RoleName,
    invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'my-function-app-site' and operation_Name =~ 'FunctionName'
```

This query gives me the information in a table however I'm interested in a graph showing the count of successes and failures on a hourly interval.
I'm not very familiar with Kusto queries, so could someone here help me with the query please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can use the below KQL query to create a time series chart showing the total success and failures for an Azure function app*

```
requests
| project
    timestamp,
    operation_Name,
    success,
    resultCode,
    duration,
    operation_Id,
    cloud_RoleName,
    invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'function app name' and operation_Name =~ 'Function name'
| extend hour = bin(timestamp, 1h) // Create hourly intervals
| summarize
    SuccessCount = sum(toint(success == 'True')),
    FailureCount = sum(toint(success == 'False'))
    by hour
| project
    hour,
    SuccessCount,
    FailureCount
| order by hour asc
| render timechart
```

**Output**

[image]

In my case there is no failure request, so I am getting zero records.